# UICollectionView deselect all

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

When handling selections with didSelectItemAtIndexPath, do you have to ensure that you use

```
cell.select = true
```

in order to get indexPathsForSelectedItems to work?

I have a collectionview that I create a red box around each thumbnail image when selected in an "edit mode".

```
cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

I want to CLEAR those boxes when "DONE" is pressed.

Calling indexPathsForSelectedItems only returns a single value and I'm not sure why? (I've tried setting cell=selected and still only get one return).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `allowsMultipleSelection` to true on your collection view.

Comment: Thanks that did it for what was visible on the screen.  I hadn't noticed that if I scrolled items off the screen that they would not repaint.  I had to check my own internal selection flags as well.  Thanks!